# Strategies for the Moon Lord?

Tags: terraria

Being the final boss of the game, I'm aware that the [Moon Lord](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Moon_Lord) is considerably harder than all prior bosses. That said, I simply don't see how defeating this boss is even remotely possible (even in vanilla, non-expert mode):

1. The Moon Bite debuff prevents all life-leech capability ([Vampire Knives](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Vampire_Knives), for example). This results in the player relying solely on healing potions. Even with a 45-second cooldown, there's not enough health-restored-per-second to deal with his damage.
2. His attacks are difficult to dodge, even with the [Cosmic Car Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cosmic_Car_Key).
3. His health stats are so high that, even with terrific end-game weapons, it takes a long time to bring each piece of him down.

I've tried using the [Phantasm](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Phantasm) with Holy Arrows, and that did great to start, but I eventually run low on health and he one-shots me (which is frustrating). Adding to all of this the fact that you have to run the lunar events again (burning 15 to 20 minutes in the process), makes this a frustrating experience.

What strategies exist to better even the odds? At the moment, it seems like the player is guaranteed to be at a major disadvantage, no matter how equipped they are. I'm aware of the "cheesing" tactics prior to 1.3.0.5 (using spikes to avoid damage), but those have been patched out of the game and are no longer viable.

Comment: Did you read the page you linked? There's a tips section, which is helpful and also provides a link to a strategy guide for defeating the moon lord. Did you try doing those? http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Moon_Lord_strategies It's quite in depth and I doubt you'll get any more information from an answer here.

Comment: With 20 pieces of each lunar fragment, you can craft the [celestial sigil](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Celestial_Sigil) which summons the "impending doom" right away, so you don't have to destroy the pillars every time.

Comment: Weren't you using a melee character? You need a full Shroomite set to even have a chance with the Phantasm. And as before the scarf and some heart statues are useful. By the way it's very important not to take the parts one by one, but the three at the same time, that way you reduce the time you have to deal with the True Eyes.

Comment: I did indeed use Shroomite armor when using the Phantasm; forgot to mention that. I'm also playing through on Normal mode, so I don't have access to the worm scarf.

Comment: Sure you can, you create a world in Expert Mode, fight the eater of worlds there and obtain the scarf to use in your normal mode world. It's a bit cheesy, but is an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aequitas's comment contains a link to the strategies page of the Terraria Gamepedia, [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Moon_Lord_strategies), this page contains most of what you would need in regards to tips and possible setups for the Moon Lord. That said, the wiki guides may be a bit cumbersome to read, and sometimes a more condensed guide could be useful. Before reading this, take into consideration that beating a boss is supposed to be a challenge and to be fun. So plan your strategy in accordance to that. And now, here are my two cents.

#### Arena

As usual with Terraria bosses a small arena before the boss fight is almost necessary. The layout may differ depending on how you plan to handle the Moon Lord. If you want to beat it in a **vanilla way**, then a 60-80 tile platform with 4 campfires and 4 heart lanterns is enough. You may add a bit of honey for extra regeneration, but the Moon Bite debuff nullifies regen, so I think is not worth it.

You can also implement a **"blockade" style** of arena, that is, add some blocks over your head and/or on the sides to prevent the non-piercing attacks. This will prevent a lot of the damage, but it will be cumbersome when attacking the boss. and you will need some special weapons, for example a bow with Holy Arrows, for their "star falling" capabilities.

Additionally you can implement a **minecart rail** arena. Which is basically and arena where you will fight the Moon Lord while riding a minecart. With the rails ends hammered to "bumper", to allow bumping at the end of the rail. This allows you to move very fast and thus a lot of attacks from the moon lord will miss.

#### Heart Statues

Now depending on the Arena chosen these statues may be crucial to the fight. In a vanilla style Arena, you will not be able to maintain you HP with potions alone, at least not with pre Moon Lord gear. Either you deal a lot of damage and die during the second stage; or you deal little damage and die from running out of gas. So for the vanilla Arena you **need** 4 statues at least, wired to a timer.

Keep in mind however that the statues spawn hearts depending on the current hearts dropped all around the world, so if you just beat the last pillar be sure to pick up the hearts from the pillar mobs, or the statues may not spawn hearts.

I believe the heart statues may not be necessary while using a minecart arena. since the cart goes really fast. So there are setups that do not require the statues because of the dodge chance they provide.

#### Armor

First, **melee** characters have a disadvantage with this boss because of its movement patters, so you can go caster, summoner or ranger.

I tried **summoner**, and it worked great on the first stage while using Tiki Armor and a Stardust Cell Staff. However by the second stage the True Eyes of Cthulhu were dealing too much damage for the armor defense, and thus I didn't survive the battle. I still think is a viable strategy, but with constant Phantasm support(I was using MegaShark that time).

I don't know much about **caster**. However, considering the main bonus of the caster armor at that point (the healing) is negated by the Moon Bite debuff, it may be better to consider other classes instead.

Finally **ranger** has Shroomite Armor, the armor itself doesn't have a lot of defense but its bonuses may prove to be very useful when fighting the boss. Remember the headgear should be different depending on the weapon chosen. As far as I know, this is the best class to fight the Moon Lord, due tho its movement patters and size of the boss.

#### Equipment

First of all, all your equipment should be reforged to "Warding", defense is really important against this boss, as you will be constantly receiving damage. That is, unless you are playing a dodge strategy, then it depends on such strategy.

Considering the defense is really important you need a Paladin shield and an Ankh shield for raw defense, you may replace one of the shields with a Worm Scarf, if you don't have any problem with using expert items in non-expert worlds(I didn't).

A crucial item is a Star Veil, or a Cross Necklace if you don't have one. The normal invincibility frames are of 1.5 seconds after receiving damage, when using these items those frames are increased to 3 seconds. this will allow you to receive tons less of hits, considering the Moon Lord is constantly attacking, specially in its second phase.

Another important Item is a Charm of Myths, the usual potion cooldown is of 1 minute, this item allows you to have a cooldown of 45 seconds, along with increased life regen. Those 15 seconds can very well save you from dying.

Finally, you need an emblem according to the class you chose, remember to have it with Warding prefix. However if you're using a Phantasm you may prefer a Magic Quiver because of the arrow speed, which will help a lot. Or you could have both and remove one of the above in which case I'd recommend removing the Charm of Myths, although you will rely more on heart statues.

Oh yeah, and you need an UFO mount, no question there, Wings require a slot, the UFO mount doesn't.

#### Weapons

I can only provide reliable information about ranger here. In that case the choice is a Phantasm with and Endless Quiver. You can use holy arrows which are of course much more effective, but they are expensive, and it will hurt you when they don't hit. So better go with endless and just "shoot all the things". Unless you have tons of holy arrows, but given the appearance of Unicorns I don't think that's the case.

I also used a Megashark with Crystal bullets the first time I beat it, and it worked well although it was much slower.

Finally I'd recommend crafting a Stardust Cell staff, even while not being a summoner, with the buffs written below you can have 3 cells running around doing extra damage, which are great help.

#### Potions

You need:

- Greater Healing Potion(or Super Healing potion if you can afford it).
- Archery Potion(Better archery if you're using a bow of course).
- Endurance Potion(Reduces damage taken by 10%).
- Wrath Potion(Increases damage by 10%).
- Rage Potion(Increases critical strike chance by 10%)
- Regeneration Potion(More health regen)
- Heartreach Potion(Increases pickup range for life hearts, important for statues)
- Ironskin Potion(Increases Defense by 8)
- Lifeforce Potion(Increases max life by 20%)
- Summoning Potion(+1 Minion capacity)
- Bewitching Table(Not potion, furniture buff, +1 Minion capacity)

Remember to "rebuff" yourself from time to time, the potions have different lasting times so you should start rebuffing after 4 minutes. Don't worry about wasting your potions, if you are already buffed the potion won't apply.

#### Boss

Key Points:

- If you see impeding doom approaching, that is the head laser, try to get hit by another projectile so the laser hits while the invincibility is active.
- It's hard to dodge the laser, however keep in mind that the closer you are to the head, the easier it will be to circle over it's head, thus dodging the laser.
- Deal damage to the three parts simultaneously, and then destroy the three of them when they are all on low HP. The True eyes of Cthulhu are invincible and deal a lot of damage, so the longer you can be without them, the better.
- The focus of the battle should not be the three parts of boss, it should be on the tongue, you keep your eyes on that tongue to be ready to kill the white essences that heal 1000 hp each. There will be three of them per tongue attack. That's the priority, when you killed the three essences, attack the parts.
- Keep shooting, specially with the Phantasm.
- When the Moon Lord is on the second stage, keep moving wildly, do not pay attention to the attacks, just move around to dodge the most you can, while on the other hand do not take your aim off the Moon Lord core, once in this stage you need to be quick, or the Eyes will overwhelm you.

And that's it. Personally I think it's the best boss, so much craziness, and yeah it's really hard, but it's good to see a challenge again.

Comment: In regards to spectre armor, since the healing doesn't work anyway, that frees up the ability to use the other spectre helmet which provides a bonus to magic instead of healing in exchange for 40% less damage. Also, a Nebula Arcanum (which you can have from pillar kills) is very effective at preventing the tongue essences from healing the moon lord.

Answer (score 5):

While some of his attacks do pass through walls, a significant number are blocked by solid walls.  Most importantly, his mouth laser and debuff tongue are blocked.

My arena is 5-6 blocks on either side to block the hands, and 7-8 blocks above to block the head, with a campfire and heart lantern.
My equipment is full Beetle (shell), with Charm of Myths and Ankh Shield.  I expect the other accessories are up to you, as long as they are reforged for some defense.
My weapons are Solar Eruption and Stardust Dragon summon since they can attack through walls, with Phantasm and Nebula Arcanum for the second stage.
For potions I am using Super Healing Potions along with Regeneration and Ironskin.  When I was using Greater Healing Potions I found I had to teleport to the Nurse to heal sometimes, but Supers enabled me to stay at the arena.

With this set-up I'm able to comfortably defeat the Moon Lord solo.
Hopefully these tips can bring you success too.

Answer (score 2):

I simply used beetle armor (any armor is fine, as long as you have >75 defense). I also built a house that had a platform roof and moved the nurse in so I could always get a heal. I used a stardust dragon and a vortex beater with chlorophyte bullets so I could stay very far away. the defense is mostly used to absorb his head laser. Always try to get all 3 eyes under 3000 health so you kill them relatively quickly. Always stay near the nurse, and heal when you have the chance. When you have killed the eyes, congrats. You've basically won. Just don't forget to heal every so often.

Comment: Healing via the Nurse turns out to be pretty key (at least it was for me). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I defeated the Moon Lord.

1. I had full Beetle armor.
2. I had full Golden hearts.
3. I had the Solar Eruption (This is key to this method.)

Alright, let's begin.

1. Build an Asphalt skybridge. (Asphalt makes you run faster, Stone + Gel)
2. Build a small house at one end of the bridge, make sure the nurse is assigned to it.

You're practically all set right now.

Now you just need to kill the Lunatic Cultist, and the pillars.

-Tips-

Make sure to heal when you're health is almost at half or at half. You don't want to be at low health running to the nurse for health.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully by the time you are reading this, you have already beaten the moon lord, and everything written here is null and void, if you haven't yet then I have some tips of my own

Starting off with gear, the first time I deafeated the moon lord, I had
Beetle armor (with shell)
Daybreak 
Ankh shield
Frostspark boots
Charm of myths
Warrior emblem
Fire gauntlet
And every buff I could get
I was also using super healing potions

My arena was a mincart rail that stretched all the way across my (large) world below the level wyverns spawn at, I was also using a mechanical minecart despite the fact that I was not in expert mode

As soon as I defeated the fourth pillar, I would teleport home and heal at the nurse, as well as pick up my buffs and get to the minecart rail.  When the moon lord spawned, I'd use my buffs, then race past him on the minecart.  Once I was a good bit past his hand on that side, id slow and try to match my speed to his, and I'd use daybreak on the hand near me.  Once that hand went down, I'd focus the forehead, it has very distinct patterns, specifically, the eye opens while charging the phantasmal death ray, after it ends, it blinks, then it closes the eye and you get hit by the tongue, after the three orbs heal it or are destroyed it repeats.  The fore head eye shouldn't be too much of a challenge, but you have to jump over the orbs the true eye of Cthulhu sends your way.  Once this eye is down, just keep going, and wait for your potion sickness to wear off.  Once your potion is up, reverse direction, you'll probably need the potion once you get past the hand. Go back to daybreak on the hand, and jumping the orbs (if possible). Once that hand is down, aim daybreak at his core and continue dodging the orbs.

That worked for me, and hopefully it'll work for you too

Answer (score -1):

In my experience a good strategy to beating moon lord is pretty simple.

**Preparations:**

1. Have full beetle armor (Shell), a stardust dragon or cell staff and a solar eruption to their best modifiers, (I believe it's godly for the staffs and godly for the solar eruption) and set all accessories to warding.
2. Have a charm of myths and an ankh shield you can choose others.
3. for the arena create a stone 8x8 house in the sky (below wyvern spawning level) and add campfires, stone walls, table and chair, heart lanterns, and a small space to add a 2x2 section of honey and make sure the honey doesn't flow out.
4. Set the house to the nurse (she will eventually die but saves you once or twice beforehand). For other healing effects I used greater healing potions and a regeneration potion Ironskin is good to use to.

**The fight:**

When the Moon Lord spawns from emblem or defeating the pillars, make sure to be in your honey blocks and drink your potions. You now have 4 effects healing you. Remember that Moon lords debuff only stops life stealing effects. Drink healing potions when needed and use nurse before healing potions because you what to make the most of her being there. Summon in the stardust dragon of cell and use solar eruption to attack his three eyes (the solar eruption goes through blocks). Lower them all to really low health and when all are at that stage attack all of them to knock them out in a short span to lower the length of time you have to deal with the true eyes of cuthulu. You may have noticed that a lot pot his attacks are blocked by the stone walls around you and one of the main things is the true eyes lasers. If they are inside your room when they use this attack it will not block them as much. When the core is expose attack it with everything and don't stop unless you need a health potion and then go back to attacking the core again. Core is the easier part of the fight for me and what I love about this strategy is you don't have to focus on dodging. If this doesn't work for you I would try one of the other answers. I tried a couple and most are effective and fun.

Answer (score -2):

Get the legendary terra blade(crafted with true Excalibur and true nights edge) and the pulse bow(bought from traveling merchant)with the venom arrows. Also get full beetle Armour and some good wings.

Comment: This is not a strategy, just a few vague pieces of gear.

Comment: I was just trying to help